# extracting entry from xml based on tag content

Tags: xml, clojure

I have an xml similar to the below

```
<countryResults>
 <countryResult>
 <PricingMode>CPM</PricingMode>
 <countryRegions>
 <Regions>
 <Region>
 <RegionID>Ds01</RegionID>
 <SensitivityAsset ID=\"19940\" ClassID=\"CreditCurve\"/>
 <RegionEntry>
 <Dimension>
 <type>Currency</type>
 <value>EUR&gt;EUR.EONIA</value>
 </Dimension>
 <Dimension>
 <type>ValueA_0</type>
 <value>87.90199815542161</value>
 </Dimension>
 <RegionValueSet>
 <Value>239.11331582</Value>
 <DsShiftPerHzShift>1.7732635616468646</DsShiftPerHzShift>
 <Credit>19940</Credit>
 </RegionValueSet>
 </RegionEntry>
 </Region>
  <Region>
 <RegionID>EMEA</RegionID>
 <RegionEntry>
 <Dimension>
 <type>Currency</type>
 <value>EUR</value>
 </Dimension>
 <Dimension>
 <type>ValueA_0</type>
 <value>-7.300000000002148</value>
 </Dimension>
 <RegionValueSet>
 <Value>0.01664004</Value>
  <Benchmark>EUR.1M3M.1B</Benchmark>
 </RegionValueSet>
 </RegionEntry>
 <RegionEntry>
 <Dimension>
 <type>Currency</type>
 <value>EUR</value>
 </Dimension>
 <Dimension>
 <type>ValueA_0</type>
 <value>-8.000000000003963</value>
 </Dimension>
 <RegionValueSet>
 <Value>-0.00057985</Value>
 <Benchmark>EUR.1M3M.1M</Benchmark>
 </RegionValueSet>
 </RegionEntry>
 <RegionEntry>
 <Dimension>
 <type>Currency</type>
 <value>EUR</value>
 </Dimension>
 <Dimension>
 <type>ValueA_0</type>
 <value>-9.400000000007434</value>
  </Dimension>
 <RegionValueSet>
 <Value>0</Value>
 <Benchmark>EUR.1M3M.3M</Benchmark>
 </RegionValueSet>
 </RegionEntry>
```

The actual xml is a lot bigger and there are varying numbers of RegionEntries inside the EMEA RegionID tag.  I basically need to search the xml and pull back all the tags within the Region where RegionID = EMEA.  I need to pull all the data from just within this branch of the xml. I.E I need to take all the dimesion, value, type, benchmark values and dump them to a file as columns.

Can someone advise on how I can do this with clojure xml?

After parsing the xml I am trying the below just to get the dimension/value tag value:

```
regions (zf/xml-> xmlmap :countryResults :countryResult :countryregions :regions :region)

    regions1(for [region regions :let [x (zf/xml-> region :region :regionID)]

                   :when (some (zf/text= "EMEA") x)]

  {:section (zf/xml1-> region :regionEntry :Dimension :value)})
```

Any advice on how to do this is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your output requirements would this help?

```
(def data (zip/xml-zip (xml/parse _INPUT_)))

(for [region (xml-> data
                    :countryResult :countryRegions :Regions :Region)
      :when (= (xml1-> region :RegionID text) "EMEA")
      entry (xml-> region :RegionEntry)]
  {:region-value-sets (for [region-value-set (xml-> entry :RegionValueSet)]
                        {:benchmark (xml1-> region-value-set :Benchmark text)
                         :value (xml1-> region-value-set :Value text)})
   :dimensions (for [dimension (xml-> entry :Dimension)]
                 {:type (xml1-> dimension :type text)
                  :value (xml1-> dimension :value text)})})
;({:region-value-sets ({:benchmark "EUR.1M3M.1B", :value "0.01664004"}),
;  :dimensions
;  ({:type "Currency", :value "EUR"}
;   {:type "ValueA_0", :value "-7.300000000002148"})}
; {:region-value-sets
;  ({:benchmark "EUR.1M3M.1M", :value "-0.00057985"}),
;  :dimensions
;  ({:type "Currency", :value "EUR"}
;   {:type "ValueA_0", :value "-8.000000000003963"})}
; {:region-value-sets ({:benchmark "EUR.1M3M.3M", :value "0"}),
;  :dimensions
;  ({:type "Currency", :value "EUR"}
;   {:type "ValueA_0", :value "-9.400000000007434"})})
```

I didn't create any helper functions on top of the basic zipper functions, but they would probably cleanup the code a bit.